# Can not access output at localhost page

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("xxxx");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);


    }
}
```

**other class**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

I made tomcat working on port 8181, because when I used 8080 and run in intellj, it says 8080 is already in use and can not start it.

So, I use 8181 and after executing, it opens localhost:8181 page but it is a white page, nothing there.

These are logs of output

> 06-Mar-2016 14:38:16.383 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:16.977 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 593 ms

These are catalina log

> 06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.878 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.32.0
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.2.0-30-generic
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.893 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.893 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_74-b02
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.894 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.894 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/caneraydin/.IntelliJIdea16/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Last5
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.895 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.896 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/caneraydin/.IntelliJIdea16/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Last5/conf/logging.properties
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.898 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.899 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.900 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.900 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.901 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.901 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.902 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/caneraydin/.IntelliJIdea16/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Last5
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:05.906 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/caneraydin/Downloads/idea-IU-144.4199.23/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.265 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.296 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.302 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-34294"]
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.304 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1704 ms
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.370 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.433 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-34294"]
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:06.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 142 ms
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:16.383 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager
>       06-Mar-2016 14:38:16.977 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 593 ms

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change the port in application.properties file to 8181 it will be default 8080
Regards,
Nitin

Comment: server.port = 8181 i did this but still same. also it says samplecontroller class never used

Comment: I think you are missing @EnableAutoConfiguration at class level

Comment: i added @ Configuration
@ EnableAutoConfiguration
@ ComponentScan
@ SpringBootApplication to main class but still same.

Comment: your config looks good.Do you get any error on executing java -jar yourjarname.jar?

Comment: Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html step by step and you should be able to get it up and running

Comment: mvn package && java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 when i do this,
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw 

i got those errros and more

Comment: It seems that it could not find any database in the classpath. Could you check if you have mentioned the embedded database in your pom.xml

Comment: Can you share your project structure and pom.xml file?